# roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch no devices connected

Tags: ros, kinect, roslaunch, libopenni, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen alot discussions regarding this topic. And i was able to install numerous libraries relating to this topic. Using the guidlines mentioned in this link on [github](https://github.com/wiedemeyer/libfreenect2), i executed the command of  ./bin/Protonect and kinect was working giving visuals. After i closed it and tried to run openni launch, it gave me this error which is mostly discussed.

```
adil@HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
... logging to /home/adil/.ros/log/1b658c1e-e2f5-11e6-90e0-e006e66a7c5d/roslaunch-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-  
PC-23624.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:38147/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
* /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
* /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
* /camera/disparity_depth/max_range: 4.0
* /camera/disparity_depth/min_range: 0.5
* /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range: 4.0
* /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range: 0.5
* /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range: 4.0
* /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range: 0.5
* /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
* /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
* /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
* /camera/driver/device_id: #1
* /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
* /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
 /camera/
camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_hw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_sw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
driver (nodelet/nodelet)
ir_rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
rgb_debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
rgb_rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
rgb_rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
/
camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [23637]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 1b658c1e-e2f5-11e6-90e0-e006e66a7c5d
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23650]
started core service [/rosout]
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [23663]
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [23668]
process[camera/rgb_debayer-4]: started with pid [23669]
process[camera/rgb_rectify_mono-5]: started with pid [23670]
process[camera/rgb_rectify_color-6]: started with pid [23689]
process[camera/ir_rectify_ir-7]: started with pid [23698]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-8]: started with pid [23714]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-9]: started with pid [23732]
[ INFO] [1485345304.154296165]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/depth_metric-10]: started with pid [23746]
process[camera/depth_points-11]: started with pid [23771]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-12]: started with pid [23775]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13]: started with pid [23784]
process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-14]: started with pid [23794]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-15]: started with pid [23805]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-16]: started with pid [23814]
process[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-17]: started with pid [23835]
process[camera/depth_registered_metric-18]: started with pid [23841]
[ INFO] [1485345304.278237517]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
process[camera/disparity_depth-19]: started with pid [23854]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-20]: started with pid [23868]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-21]: started with pid [23886]
process[camera_base_link-22]: started with pid [23896]
process[camera_base_link1-23]: started with pid [23900]
process[camera_base_link2-24]: started with pid [23905]
process[camera_base_link3-25]: started with pid [23918]
[ INFO] [1485345307.278613401]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1485345310.279014898]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1485345313.279387071]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [148534
```

Im using ROS Indigo 14.04 LTS with processor Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4  and the graphics is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile. Im using Kinect V2.

Im totally out of options of how to proceed and still want to figure out how to make things work using kinect V2. Kindly provide me with suggestions or solutions on how to make kinect v2 start working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252971/roslaunch-openni_launch-openni.launch-no-devices-connected/) by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-25**:
Just a note: please don't indent lines with 4 spaces or more, as that is how code blocks and performatted text gets recognised on this forum. I've updated your question already, but keep it in mind for next time.

**Comment by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on 2017-01-26**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for updating. My error for not writing in proper format. Forgot to write in proper format. Any suggestions on the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, afaik, the Kinect2 isn't compatible with the infrastructure that the `openni` package provides. I would try getting `iai_kinect2` working.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on 2017-02-03**:
@gvdhoorn thank you. Your advice definitely helped me. Now i am able to access kinect properly.